# Any way to extract the Encoding name of a cell in Excel sheet?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, export-to-excel

The problem is the cell text in Excel sheet can be encoded using some Encoding table, the most popular one is Unicode Encoding table (for non-English language), but other Encoding tables do exist. So to convert the cell text in Excel sheet to Unicode text, I have to know the source Encoding (there are some Encoding tables for my language besides Unicode namely VNI, VPS, VISCII, TCVN3, VIQR), I wonder how to extract that information from the cells when reading Excel file?

You can give me a solution using any Excel library possible. I'm using NPOI and with it, I've still not found out how to do (I'm a little new to NPOI).

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, which version of excel are you working with?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013 (Excel 15) but I don't think it matters.